# How to install Bomgar Jump Client so that it starts when the system boots also

Tags: linux-mint

My question adds on to this one:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232859/help-with-a-line-of-shell

Question: How to have this start up when the Linux box is booted to enable a remote session.

I use Bomgar (www.bomgar.com) to support remote clients,  other than a few installations.I'm not interested in Windows 10 and really want to move to a Linux environment for myself.

I already contacted Bomgar support, but they were no help other than the following they handed me from their support docs:  "To install a Jump Client in service mode on a Linux system, the Jump Client must be installed as root. This will NOT cause the Jump Client to run as root. A service mode Jump Client allows the user to start a session even if no remote user is logged on, as well as to log off the current remote user and log on with different credentials. A Linux Jump Client installed in user mode cannot be elevated within a session."  When I asked them HOW to do that, they couldn't offer me any information.

On a Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon installation, I am able to install the Bomgar client on the system, and when a user logs in, it becomes active until the user logs out. I have an installation installed under each user account, but this just isn't effective.

I temporarily enabled Root after giving it a password, and installed that way as well, but it doesn't "auto start" when the system boots up, and remote access isn't available until a user logs in.  I then tried to set it up as "auto start" in the Linux installation after searching for it, and I enabled that too, but again, it only works if someone logs in first.  But, it does stay active after they log out.  However, even though it's active, I can't remotely connect and see anything but a black screen, and no possibility of logging in.  So that's not working either, but I feel I'm getting close.

Answer (score 1):

Bomgar actually does work on Linux without the GUI.

Did you see the bottom section of this article?
[Deploy Jump Clients During a Support Session or Prior to Support](https://www.bomgar.com/docs/content/features/jump-clients/deploying.htm)

The "Prior to Support" section at the bottom ought to apply.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

unlike windows the GUI is not part of the operating system.

if you want a graphical application like bomgar to run when there is no user logged in install it also under the account that runs the login manager.

Comment: Thanks Jasen -- which account runs the login manager?  I'm definitely not very experienced with Linux, but plan on learning as much as I can. If you or anyone else has any recommendations on books to get started with Linux I'm all ears.  I'm Not new to computers/servers/networks/programming but Linux is definitely new territory for me.

Comment: @SunFreeze it depends (I don't know enough about mint to guess)... with he login screen active switch to a console (strl-alt-f1) and log in then run the command `w`  that will list the active users, one of them will be the login process. as root find that user;s home directory "cd ~USERNAME" and look for a  `.xsession` file, it should be possible to add the needed commands there.